# Unable to bind SPC as a prefix in general (evil mode)

Tags: key-bindings, evil, use-package

My setup worked perfectly fine, however I recently reinstalled Emacs and therefore updated all packages as well when starting for the first time.

Since then I cant get rid of the warning/error: 
`Error (use-package): general/:config: Key sequence SPC x starts with non-prefix key SPC`

Relevant part of my config:

```
(general-define-key
   :states '(normal emacs motion)
   :prefix "SPC"

   "x" 'counsel-M-x )
```

I already tried:

- unbinding SPC before it is used as a prefix
- have my keybindings load after everything else
- using alternative definitions for using spacebar  to "SPC" for example with kbd

What is especially weird to me, is that the keybinding and all others that are prefixed with `SPC` work perfectly fine like they should (even `SPC x`). `C-h k SPC` also gives me the associated results.
I also know that this is related to `general.el` especially because manually copying and using an old copy of the package doesn't give me this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using general too. I successfully got rid of this error (see part of my `.emacs` that does this in the picture below). The space key in `evil-motion-state` is bound to something so you have to set it to nil before `general` can bind it. I don't think the `evil-normal-state` binds anything to space but I did the same thing for it just in case. I think to make your code work you'd just do what I did but add emacs state too. So try adding this line before using the any `:prefix SPC` bindings:

```
(general-def :states '(normal motion emacs) "SPC" nil)
```

One warning though. I'm not sure this is something you want to do for `evil-emacs-state`. What will happen is you wont be able to insert a space whenever you're in emacs state because it will be defined as a prefix key. I don't think this makes much sense considering it's kind of like an insert state.

[image: part of my emacs config with space key]

Comment: Perfect solution for my problem and also made some things clearer to me (Y)